# Align to center JO K2 Slideshow

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2

How to aling to center JO K2 Slideshow of my web site? 
http://www.enpi-medscapes.org/index.php/en/

Comment: This question is not truly an issue for the JSE and should have been asked on the K2 forums. Please remember JSE is here to help with Joomla related issues.

Comment: Although this is not one of the best questions possible, -4 votes is too much

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what template you're using, but a CSS solution would be as follows:

```
.jo-k2-slidecontent {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: purity_III - Joomlart

Answer (score 1):

In your `custom.css` you have this:

```
.jo-k2-slidecontent {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 1px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.jo-k2-slidecontent {
    margin-left: 450px;
}
```

Actually, you have to remove the second rule with the left margin, and fix an issue you have on the first rule, where you don't have the semicolon `;` after the `border: 1px solid #cccccc`.

So your `custom.css` should end up like this:

```
.jo-k2-slidecontent {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 1px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```